# Stylecop SA1001 warning

Tags: c#, stylecop

why does the following code give me a SA1001 warning?

```
Class test = new Test
{
    Test1 = "1"
    , Test2 = "2"
    , Test3 = "3"
};
```

I've checked documentation which says that to avoid this warning my commas should not be preceeded by a space unless they're the first thing on a line, and should have a space after them unless they're the last thing on the line, but this isn't getting rid of the warning. I don't want to supress the rule in general only in this specific case.

Comment: Because there is invalid spacing around comma in your code. Read [Here](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1001.md) to understand the rule.

Comment: Ah this makes sense, I wasn't aware that I couldn't have a comma as the start of a line. This is a pain as this is my preferred way of doing this

Answer (score 0):

Your `,` are place wrongly. It should be like below; which will get rid off that said StyleCop error

```
Class test = new Test
{
    Test1 = "1",
    Test2 = "2",
    Test3 = "3", //also ends with another ,
};
```